# Find a combination $x_1w_1 + x_2w_2 + x_3w_3$ that gives the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem is described [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/ax-b-and-the-four-subspaces/the-geometry-of-linear-equations/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses1.1sol.pdf) with a given solution:

> [image]

I don't understand why the answer is not simply $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0$.

Thanks

Comment: The aim is to show that $w_1,w_2,w_3$ are linearly dependent. In order to say that you should find a nontrivial combination (i.e. at least one coefficient is nonzero) $x_1w_1+x_2w_2+x_3w_3=0$.

Comment: Because that is the trivial solution. To see whether or not the three given vectors are *linearly independent* (and hence forms a *basis*), you need to see if a *non-trivial* solution exists to the system of linear equations given by $x_1w_1+x_2w_2+x_3w_3=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the goal for Problem 1.1 is to see whether the $w_i$'s are linearly independent or not. The equality 
$$
w_1-2w_2+w_3=0
$$
tells you that they are not. But $0w_1+0w_2+0w_3=0$ tells you nothing.

Comment: I did not get how first equality tells you they are not linearly independent and second does not...

Comment: What is the *definition* of "linearly independent"?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is a perfectly good answer to a badly phrased question. It should have asked "find a nontrivial combination" or "find a combination, with not all coeffs being zero" or (better) show that these vectors are dependent by finding a combination with not all three coeffs being zero".